# Xamarin.Forms: Get if side menu from master detail is currently visible?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to change a button in the side menu drawer, depening on whether the user is logged in or not. I hoped I could simply just check everytime the side menu is opened via the burger icon by overriding OnAppearing():

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        SetButtonAccordingToPosition();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this function is only called ONCE when the app starts and then never again anymore.

I need to find out when the side menu is visible. How would i do that?

Comment: MasterDetailPage.IsPresented

Comment: Yep, that is it.